# SQL Server crash

Tags: sql-server, crash

I had SQL Server 2016 in one of our servers, then I decided to install SSIS AND SSAS for Bi purpose, and I tried to install these two services (SSAS AND SSRS) in another instance.

After installing the second Instance, I noticed that: I can't connect to the first instance SQL databases (It has been somehow replaced by the second instance).

I get this message when I connect to database:

[image]

I get this message while restarting the service:

[image]

In SQL Server configuration manager there no service for the first Instance:

[image]

That's the last records in my SQL log file:

```
2020-08-23 14:46:11.87 Backup      RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 96898 pages in 21.859 seconds (34.631 MB/sec).
2020-08-23 17:35:02.25 Server      SQL Server is terminating because of a system shutdown. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2020-08-23 17:35:02.32 spid12s     Always On: The availability replica manager is going offline because SQL Server is shutting down. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2020-08-23 17:35:02.53 spid40s     Service Broker manager has shut down.
2020-08-23 17:35:02.53 spid40s     Error: 17054, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2020-08-23 17:35:02.53 spid40s     The current event was not reported to the operating system error log. Operating system error = (null). You may need to clear the operating system error log if it is full.
2020-08-23 17:35:02.53 spid12s     .NET Framework runtime has been stopped.
2020-08-23 17:35:09.04 spid12s     [INFO] Database ID: [18]. Cleaning up StorageArray. LastClosedCheckpointEndTs: '55'
```

Questions:

1. How can I get back to my previous state of SQL Server (the mdf and ldf files exist in their location but I can't find masterdb files)?
2. Is there a way to restore users and SQL jobs?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the instance was uninstalled unless you, or someone else, told it to be. Either during the new installation or before/after. If it truly has been uninstalled, the only way to get to where you were is with backups.

Comment: so based on above situation and error messages what has happend?and how can i figure out the reason?  
I can reattach the mdf and ldf files,but the problem is that I loos the security detail(which user has access to which db and..) and I also will loos my sql jobs.
is there any solution to find jobs and security prpperties?

Comment: *"what has happend?"* Without knowing the steps you took, very difficult to know. Why I said that you, or someone, likely (in error) uninstalled the instance. And, like I said, if you have backups of the databases you *can* get back to where you were. Hopefully you also have scripted out your logins and your sql jobs. If not, if you have backups of `msdb`/`master` you *can* restore those, but they come with a lot of considerations and yu have to be **very** careful when you do. Fortunately, if you're restoring to a fresh instance, there's not a lot you can break.

Comment: only things that has happens are two process as below :
Installing another Instance of sql server
uninstalling SSDT ! and then Sql server crashed!

Comment: If the instance "crashed" it would still be installed. Your limited screenshots suggest you have no instance installed.